# Where to read the time a client connected to a hosted network or hotspot?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, arp, netsh

I have created a hotspot via netsh commands in Windows 8.1.

Here are the list of commands I've used but there no details about the time in a client connected to the hosted network.

```
> netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="sampleName" key="12345678"

> netsh wlan start hosted network

> netsh wlan stop hosted network

> netsh wlan show hostednetwork
```

I've also used the arp command but it only displays the IP addresses.

```
> arp -a
```

Would it be possible to retrieve such information? If not, are there workarounds?

Hope to hear some enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

In the Control panel/Windows firewall/Advanced settings->Action->Properties enable logging via "Customize" button in the logging section. Set to "Yes"  "Log successful connections".  You can also override there default location (%systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log) of log file.

Comment: This is useful although the information I'd like to get about the time in and time out for a specific connected devices with an IP I was looking for was not on the list. But this will be helpful in the future. Thanks for this. I'll vote up for your answer.

Comment: I think that information you are looking for "the time in and time out for a specific connected devices with an IP I was looking for was not on the list." isn't provided by standard windows environment, because windows's WiFi hotspot isn't so advanced and supposed to be used as a simple sharing. You may need some 3rd party  advanced software to get what you want or you can write some simple log parser that will filter firewall log to spot information you're looking for.